# Update Windows Registry for all users

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a piece of script to update windows registry. But it turned out that it works only for the users who ran the script. The script is shown as below. Can anyone tell me how to apply the changes to all users in a computer?

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.sapssd] @="SapFront.App"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.ssd] @="SapFront.App"

Answer (score 5):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a pseudo registry hive that contains both the keys found in the per-user settings under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and the system-global settings under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`. Writes to the `HKCR` pseudo hive go to the per-user settings under `HKCU`. If you want to update the system-global settings you should write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead.