# How do I lock Chrome User Profile?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I found that my Chrome profile was occasionally switched to older account, and I'd like to lock my current profile. Is there a way to do so? Either through policy or regedit or even some scripting is welcome.

Comment: Try this [method](http://batemanbasketball.com/lock-google-chrome-with-password/)

Comment: I guess, by _lock_, OP means to set one chrome profile as the default profile and prevent it from changing.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome always starts with the last-open profile that was being used before Chrome closed. But, it is possible to start Chrome with a specific profile with the `--profile-directory="name of profile"` option.
Here, "name of profile" follows the naming convention *Default*, *"Profile 1"*, *"Profile 2"* etc. provided you added the profiles using the *Add person* option in Chrome. There's a detailed explanation about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/).

There is no reliable way to ensure that Chrome always starts with a specific profile, but there are some ways to get it working temporarily.

(I am assuming you are using Chrome on Windows because you have tagged the question as *windows-10*)

To make sure Chrome always starts with a particular profile **when you open it**, you can suffix the `--profile-directory="name of profile"` argument to all the Chrome shortcuts on your taskbar, start menu, Desktop, etc.
**Note:** Make sure you don't edit the *All Users* shortcut located in `\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` on a multi-user system otherwise you might break Chrome for other users of the PC, plus you need admin rights for that. A better way would be to create a new Chrome shortcut for your current user account in `\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and edit that instead.

To make Chrome start with a specific profile **when you click a link elsewhere** or use the **open with** option and select *Chrome*, you can suffix the `--profile-directory="name of profile"` argument to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command` registry key.
The details of this are already included in the answer for this question [here](https://superuser.com/a/811878/995873). You don't need to worry about messing with multi-user settings (see details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/529232/)). However, from personal experience, this setting does get reset to the default value (i.e. with no particular profile directory) once in a while, possibly when Chrome updates.